# Bring elements from back to front animation javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a dynamic website. It has some smaller elements (div) in the background and some larger elements in the foreground. I want , as the user scrolls, to bring the smaller elements from the background to the front, with a nice 3D effect. Is there any jQuery / js library that can help me achieve that? I found nothing so far.

Comment: Code is helpful, especially to clarify statements like "...some smaller elements (div) in the background and some larger elements in the foreground", which is astonishingly ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out CSS3 animations - see http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transforms/

Its not something you really need a library for, but if you're looking for a fun animations library, check out http://impulse.luster.io/